Is there any plugin or way to use Lipsync system Metahuman on MOBİLE ? UNREAL ENGİINE
For a Unreal Engine Mobile (android) project which includes Metahuman, LipSync, Speech Recognition system.
I really need info real quick. Im looking for a way to use lipsync to my metahuman project. I'll use it on an Android device.
I have already a system on the project. It uses external folders. Just like voks, language folders and etc. But it only supports windows. It doesn't includes mobile devices. If im able to use it on mobile device, i am okey with it. Can you just tell me what can i do about it ?

Welcome to StackOverflow. This site works best with specific programming questions. Please read How to Ask as it seems like you looking for a off-topic recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource.  Generally you should research any library to see if supports a desired platform before using it. Good luck.

Questions about site moderation do not belong in your question - I rolled back that edit. Aside from that: your question is off-topic, as there is no programming question, and no details from you (a [mcve]) - just a plea for recommendations (this is the likely reason you received so many downvotes). Also: this site has no SLA - it's volunteer-driven. There is no "real quick" here.
